# Trailing Zeroes of a Factorial

Tags: java, performance, integer

I'm trying to solve this coding question:
Given an integer n, return the number of trailing zeroes in n!

Below is my code (codec this up using the [wiki link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trailing_zero))

```
    public int trailingZeroes(int n) {
        int count = 0, i = 5;
        while(i<=n){
            count+= n/i;
            i*=5;
        }
        return count;
   }
```

This runs for all test cases except when n = Integer.MAX_VALUE upon which I get a TLE. How can I fix this code to make it cover that test case. I have read about five articles on the net and everything seems to agree with my approach.

Much thanks.

So, I followed the long/BigInteger approach (thanks y'all):

```
    public int trailingZeroes(int n) {
    long count = 0;
    for(long i= 5; n/i >= 1; i= i*5){
        count+= n/i;
    }
    return (int)count;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to compute the number of trailing zeroes of `n!` where `n` is `Integer.MAX_VALUE`?.  That's certainly too huge to fit into the precision of a normal integer.

Comment: If I get your comment, I am not trying to compute the factorial here. So I don't understand how I could fix the TLE.

Comment: I am thinking of using a... BigInteger?

Comment: You said you wanted to compute the trailing zeroes in `n!`, so naturally I would have thought you wanted to compute `n!` first.  However, looking at that wiki link, it looks like you don't need to!

Comment: Ah, no. The point here is not to calculate the factorial but to count the no of 5s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that once `i` gets large enough (more than `Integer.MAX_INT / 5`) then the line `i*=5;` causes `i` to overflow to the "wrong" value.  The value in question is 5 to the 14th power, which is `6103515625`, but which overflows to 1808548329.

The result of this is that the loop just keeps executing forever.  `i` will never become a value that's not `<= Integer.MAX_INT`, because there's just no such `int`.

To avoid this, you need `i` to be a larger data type than an `int`.  If you change `i` and `count` in your original code to `long`, this will work fine.  Of course, `BigInteger` would also work.

Answer (score 4):

As Iaune observed, your loop will never terminate when `n` is `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, because there is no `int` greater than that number (by definition).  You should be able to restructure your loop to avoid that problem.  For instance, this is the same basic approach, but flipped upside-down:

```
public int trailingZeroes(int n) {
    int count = 0;

    while (n > 0) {
        n /= 5;
        count += n;
    }

    return count;
}
```

Comment: Personally, I think this form is also a little easier to understand.

Comment: What does /= do ? is that the same as += ?

Comment: @jackdh, `/=` is *analogous to* `+=`, if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot write a for or while loop where the loop counter is an int and the upper limit is `<= Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

What happens with a simple increment (counter++) is that the loop counter is set to that value, the body executes and then the counter is incremented which results in a *negative number*, Integer.MIN_VALUE. And then everything happens all over again.

Other weird things may happen when the loop counter is incremented in quantities > 1 or (as here) is multiplied: the int loop counter just can't hold a value > Integer.MAX_VALUE

Consider another approach for iterating over these numbers. Or handle MAX_VALUE separately.

Comment: Fair enough that the overflow doesn't yield a negative value in this particular case, but the main point is that the condition must always to `true`.

Comment: @DavidWallace OK, I've discussed various possibilities in addition to the simple counter++.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class FactorialNumberTrailingZeros {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(trailingZeroes(1000020));
    }

    private static int trailingZeroes(int n) {
        int count = 0;
        while (n > 0 && (n % 10 == 0)) {
            n /= 10;
            count ++;
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int result = findFactorialTrailingZero(100);

    System.out.println("no of trailing zeros are " + result);


}

public static int findFactorialTrailingZero(int no) {
    int zeros = no / 5;

    int zeroIncrementNo = 25;
    int zerosIncrementFactor = 1;
    int nextZeroIncrenent = 5;

    for (int i = 1;no >= zeroIncrementNo; i++) {
        zeros=zeros+zerosIncrementFactor;
        zeroIncrementNo=25*(i+1);

        if(i+1==nextZeroIncrenent){
            zerosIncrementFactor++;
            nextZeroIncrenent=nextZeroIncrenent*5;
        }

    }
    return zeros;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
   /*
    [n/5]+[n/25]+[n/125]+....
    if n<25 then [n/5]
    if n<125 then [n/5]+[n/25]
    if n<625 then [n/5]+[n/25]+[n/125]
    */

#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int countTrailingZeroes(int n)
{
    int res=0;                             
    for(int i=5;i<=n;i=i*5){
         res=res+n/i;
    }
    return res;
}
int main(){
ios::sync_with_stdio(0); cin.tie(0); cout.tie(0);
int n;
cin>>n;
cout<<countTrailingZeroes(n);

return 0;
}
```

Output

```
25
6
```

Explanation:
25!=1.551121e+25 i.e contains 6 trailing zeroes

Answer (score -1):

Here is my python code that could solve your problem:

```
    def check(n):
        j,ans=5,0
        while j<=n:
            ans=ans+n//j
            j=j*5
        return ans
```